# Import text file into a table in db2

Tags: sql, db2

Text file contains data like

1,'name',34

2,'name1',23

Comment: Sql Developer..

Comment: I need a query to do this ..

Comment: Which operating system runs the Db2-server?  (Z/os,  os400 i series , or  linux/unix/windows/cloud ) ?

Comment: Windows........

Comment: Is the Db2-database on the *same* hostname as the Oracle-SQL-Developer GUI?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Access Client Solutions, you can use the File Transfer function to upload the file.

Also can upload directly from Excel if the file is open:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/transferring-data-excel-using-access-client-solutions

Answer (score 0):

When the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, you can CALL a stored procedure to do import or load.

BUT, the file to be imported or loaded *must* already be on the Db2-server, or on a file-system that the Db2-server process can read. So any filenames are *relative* to the Db2-server (not to your workstation, unless of course the Db2-server runs on your workstation).

If the target table already exists, the connected-userid needs suitable permissions on that table. If the target table does not exist, you need to create it first.

Also the userid needs execute permission on the stored procedure that does the work.

So there are three steps:

- copy the file to be imported (or loaded) to a location that the Db2-server can read.
- call the ADMIN_CMD stored procedure with parameters telling it what to do, in this case to import a file.
- Examine the result-set of the stored procedure to see what happened.  If the import or load failed, you need to run the SQL listed in the MSG_RETRIEVAL column of the result-set to see why it failed (assuming you used MESSAGES ON SERVER option to import).

See the Db2 documentation online here for [import](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023575.html) or [load](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html)
There are also many examples here on stackoverflow.
So do your research and learn.

Answer (score 0):

On Db2 11.5 you can use a REMOTE TABLE to import a text file into Db2

Use the REMOTESOURCE YES option if the file is on your client and not on a directory visible to the database server

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_create_ext_table.html?pos=2